# Dragonvale Breeding community wiki?

Tags: discussion

Similar to what Bicycles.SE has [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index), why can't we have a community wiki for "How to breed x Dragons"?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, you could at provide your opinion on the 'why can't we' bit of his question.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  What makes Dragonvale questions different than others?

Comment: Most questions are just "How do I breed x dragon".  Having one page addresses any new dragons that may come in the future

Comment: Why is having one page with a whole ton of answers to search through better than having separate pages that make it easy to find what you want?

Comment: @Retrosaur While I wish Arqade was more welcoming of DragonVale breeding questions, I don't think a community wiki is the answer.  The Stack engine works best for discrete ask-answer relationships.  With more than 100 dragons in dragonvale, and many times that many potential breeding pairs - I believe it is far better to deal with them one question at a time.

Answer (score 4):

This was [proposed before](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5007/13845) and not very warmly received by the community.  There are some points raised in the comments on that answer that I think are relevant.

After the [fallout due to a previous Dragonvale discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/are-dragonvale-questions-that-are-easy-to-answer-bad-questions) there have been far fewer Dragonvale breeding questions on the site - I count 2 breeding-related questions from the last month, despite the current in-game promotion that allows any previous limited-time dragon to be bred again.

I'm not sure there's really a problem to solve here, and if there is, this isn't a solution  that people seem interested in.